# How can I use QueryDSL in a custom MongoRepository in Spring Data

Tags: spring-data, querydsl

The Title is quite self explanatory, but...

Guys, I'm using a MongoRepository with QueryDSL like:

```
interface MyRepository 
extends MongoRepository<MyObject, String>,
        MyRepositoryCustom,
        QuerydslPredicateExecutor<MyObject>
```

How can I use QueryDSL in my custom repository `MyRepositoryCustom`?

I have an Interface:

```
interface MyRepositoryCustom {

    Optional<MyObject> findUsingValues(String value1, String value2);

}
```

I want to use the `findOne` that receive a `Predicate` as parameter in my Impl like:

```
public class MyRepositoryCustomImpl implements MyRepositoryCustom {

    @Override
    Optional<MyObject> findUsingValues(String value1, String value2){

        BooleanBuilder builder = new BooleanBuilder();
        //Mount builder with values and Query Objects

        return findOne(builder.get());//How can I make this line work?
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
I tried to extend de `QuerydslPredicateExecutor` in `MyRepositoryCustomImpl` but the method is never reached. I think that is because of the unique constructor required by `QuerydslPredicateExecutor`.

e.g:

```
public class MyRepositoryCustomImpl extends QuerydslPredicateExecutor<MyObject> implements MyRepositoryCustom {

    public MyRepositoryCustomImpl(MongoEntityInformation<MyObject, ?> entityInformation, MongoOperations mongoOperations) {
        super(entityInformation, mongoOperations);
    }

    @Override
    Optional<MyObject> findUsingValues(String value1, String value2){

        BooleanBuilder builder = new BooleanBuilder();
        //Mount builder with values and Query Objects

        return findOne(builder.get());//How can I make this line work?
    }
}
```